# Why do the elements not appear in random places but they are staying aligned on top of the div?

Tags: javascript, random, position, appendchild

The code is supposed to generate 5 elements one by one so that when the page is downloaded all we`ll see 5 elements (newFace) in random places.

This code generates all 5 elements but they are staying aligned one by one instead of appearing in random position as wished

```
function generate_faces() {
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    var number_of_faces = 0;
    while (number_of_faces < 5){
        var top_position = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
        var left_position = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
        newFace = document.createElement("img");
        newFace.setAttribute(
          "src",
          "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png"
        );
        newFace.style.top = top_position+"px";
        newFace.style.left = left_position+"px";
        theLeftSide.appendChild(newFace);
        number_of_faces = number_of_faces + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: is the "leftSide" positioned relative, the img absolute some place?

Comment: leftSide and img are both positioned absolute in css (the task told that they have to have position:absolute)

Comment: Can you make an [executable Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7dkfmes9/1/

Comment: I checked one more time - and found a bug in CSS, now it works for me as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
html, body, leftSide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#leftSide {
    position: relative;
}

#leftSide img {
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<body onclick="generate_faces()">
<div id="leftSide">

</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function generate_faces() {

var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var number_of_faces = 0;
while (number_of_faces < 5){
    var top_position = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    var left_position = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    newFace = document.createElement("img");
    newFace.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png"
    );
    newFace.style.top = top_position+"px";
    newFace.style.left = left_position+"px";
    theLeftSide.appendChild(newFace);
    number_of_faces = number_of_faces + 1;
  }
}
</script>
```